# Jetpack compose unresolved reference errors

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, androidx

**I'm keep getting this issues please help to fix these.
I want to show an animated drawable in jetpack compose.**

**Error -**

```
e: /myproject/../MainActivity.kt: (42, 17): Unresolved reference: animatedVectorResource
e: /myproject/../MainActivity.kt: (43, 18): Unresolved reference: remember
e: myproject/../MainActivity.kt: (43, 29): Unresolved reference: mutableStateOf
```

**I have these imports -**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.foundation.isSystemInDarkTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffect
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import com.google.accompanist.systemuicontroller.rememberSystemUiController
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
```

**My Code**

```
val image = animatedVectorResource(R.drawable.test)
    var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Image(painter = image.painterFor(atEnd),contentDescription = "",modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds)
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        Text("Hello")
        Text("World")
    }
```

Please help me out.
[I use this IDE.](https://github.com/AndroidIDEOfficial/AndroidIDE) 
I'm learning jetpack compose, means I am total beginner in jetpack compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `remember` and  `mutableStateOf` add these import statements:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
```

For `animatedVectorResource` add the `androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics` dependency and use

```
 import androidx.compose.animation.graphics.res.animatedVectorResource
 import androidx.compose.animation.graphics.vector.AnimatedImageVector

 val image = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(R.drawable.test)
```